# Android facebook passing information between users

Tags: android, facebook

I'm developing an Android game, and now I'm in the stage where I want to create a multiplayer option. 
My task it to pass between two users on different phones an integer.

My thought is to do it via facebook, to enjoy all the social benefits of it.

Do you know what API's\technologies I need to use? 
I installed the facebook SDK, but cant find the specific API's to do it.

Thanks Allot, Vlady.

Comment: Why would you want to use facebook SDK for passing an integer between two users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two users play against each other (or with each other) then the best approach would be a P2P connection, that it the two devices should have a socket between them for passing messages.

If that's not possible for some reason, then the fallback would be to have a central server to which all clients are connected, this server will then route the message from user A to user B.

As for the facebook option, what's the point?
It's not what their api is for.
You can use the [Achievements](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/achievements/) to publish user scores and such, gain more engagement and virality, but that's not for the communication between the clients.